# PHP form not submitting on new host

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created a custom form for a client whose website was built on my company's staging server. The form is working correctly on our staging server, but now that I moved it over to the client's server, it's no longer working. Inside the JS, ajax is calling an absolute URL for apex-email.php to process the form. I did narrow down that if I use the URL to where the file is located on our staging server, it works. If I change it to where it's located on their server, it doesn't work, so I'm assuming it's an ajax issue? Here's my code:

HTML:

```
                            <form id="apex-form" class="form-horizontal">

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="firstname">First name: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="lastname">Last name: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="name">Email: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control"  type="email" name="email" id="email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="phone">Phone: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control"  type="tel" name="phone" id="phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="company">Company Name: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="company" id="company">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="website">Website URL:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="website" id="website">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="address">Street Address: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="addresstwo">Address Line 2:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="addresstwo" id="addresstwo">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="city">City: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="state">State: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <select class="form-control validate[required]" name="state" id="state">
                                            <option value="">Please Select One</option>
                                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                                            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                            <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="zip">Zip: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zip" id="zip">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <hr/>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="numbercustomers">Number of Customers: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control"  type="number" name="numbercustomers" id="numbercustomers">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="averageemp">Average Number of Employees per Customer: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control"  type="number" name="averageemp" id="averageemp">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="numberchecks">Number of Checks Per Month: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control"  type="number" name="numberchecks" id="numberchecks">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="currentsoftware">Current Payroll Software: <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="currentsoftware" id="currentsoftware">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label class="col-sm-12" for="howhear">How did you hear about us? <span class="red-star">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="howhear" id="howhear">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12"><label class="col-sm-12"  for="addcomments">Additional Comments:</label><br/>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12"><textarea name="addcomments" id="addcomments" class="form-control col-sm-12 textarea" rows="3"></textarea></div>
                                </div>



                                <div class="form-group col-md-12"><button type="submit" name="send" class="free-button btn btn-default" id="submitBtn">Submit</button></div>

                            </form>
```

JS:

```
$('#apex-form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {

            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true
            },
            company: {
                required: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true
            },
            city: {
                required: true
            },
            state: {
                required: true
            },
            zip: {
                required: true
            },
            numbercustomers: {
                required: true
            },
            averageemp: {
                required: true
            },
            numberchecks: {
                required: true
            },
            currentsoftware: {
                required: true
            },
            howhear: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var data = $(form).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://mycompanysstagingsite.com/wp-content/themes/apex/apex-email.php', 
                data: $("#apex-form").serialize(),
                success: function(d){
                       $(".form-wrap").hide();
                       $(".result").show(d);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

apex-email.php:

```
<?php

$to  = 'example@email.com'; 


$subject = 'Example Subject';

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$emailTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


     $firstname = 'First Name: ' . $_POST['firstname'] . "\r\n";
     $lastname = 'Last Name: ' . $_POST['lastname'] . "\r\n";
     $email = 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
     $phone = 'Main Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\r\n";
     $company = 'Company Name: ' . $_POST['company'] . "\r\n";
     $website = 'Website: ' . $_POST['website'] . "\r\n";
     $address = 'Address 1: ' . $_POST['address'] . "\r\n";
     $addresstwo = 'Address 2: ' . $_POST['addresstwo'] . "\r\n";
     $city = 'City: ' . $_POST['city'] . "\r\n";
     $state = 'State: ' . $_POST['state'] . "\r\n";
     $zip = 'Zip: ' . $_POST['zip'] . "\r\n";
     $referral = 'Referral: Apex Contact Info Web Form' . "\r\n"; 
     $numbercustomers = '# of Clients: ' . $_POST['numbercustomers'] . "\r\n"; 
     $averageemp = 'Active # of EEs: ' . $_POST['averageemp'] . "\r\n";
     $numberchecks = '# of Checks/Month: ' . $_POST['numberchecks'] . "\r\n";
     $currentsoftware = 'Current Software: ' . $_POST['currentsoftware'] . "\r\n";
     $addcomments = "Prospect's Comments:  " . $_POST['addcomments']; 


    $emailmessage = $firstname .' '. $lastname .' '. $phone .' ' . $email .' ' . $company .' ' . $website .' ' . $address .' ' . $addresstwo .' ' . $city .' ' . $state .' ' . $zip .' ' . $referral .' ' . $numbercustomers .' ' . $averageemp .' ' . $numberchecks .' ' . $currentsoftware .' ' . $addcomments;




$headers = 'From: example@email.com ' . "\r\n"; // From email
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path : ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $emailTime, $emailmessage, $headers);


?>
```

EDIT: I'm looking into this being a possible GoDaddy issue and how they have things configured on their end.

Comment: Where is the error? What does the error say? Have you checked both php error logs and the the console for errors? *It doesn't work* doesn't help anyone help you :p

Comment: @skrilled - that's what I'm trying to figure out. :) It's working on our server perfectly fine. It doesn't seem to want to run the apex-email.php on their server, though.

Comment: Let me check the PHP error logs.

Comment: Without physical access to your server, or the ability to run your code on your server, nobody here can find the error for you. If you do not know how to display the js console, I can help get you to the point that you know the error so that someone can help fix though.

Comment: JS console and PHP error logs are both empty with no errors

Comment: "I did narrow down that if I use the URL to where the file is located on our staging server, it works. If I change it to where it's located on their server, it doesn't work" - you are changing the URL to a different server than where this ajax script is located? Are cross origin headers set up on their end? After re-reading your question it sounds like you should at least see an error period when submitting :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109183/discussion-between-brittany-layne-rapheal-and-skrilled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like I suspected, it had nothing to do with Cross Origin (because it was calling a file on the same server... there's no crossing involved). It had to do with how the headers were set up. The `$emailTime` variable was causing the form to break when being submitted. Apparently, that's not a proper format for headers. When I included `$emailTime` as part of the `$emailmessage`, the form submitted just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're having cross origin scripting issues:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://inwardstaging.com/apex2/wp-content/themes/apex/apex-email.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.thepayrollcloud.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

You either need to add cross origin friendly headers to the `apex-email.php` script, i.e.:

```
 <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.thepayrollcloud.com");
```

Or if you aren't worried about the security of any site accessing it:

```
 <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Or change the location of the script on `www.thepayrollcloud.com` to point to a copy local to the website if this has the same files. (probably best solution)

```
url: '/wp-content/themes/apex/apex-email.php',
```

Comment: It's not cross origin, though. In their JS on their server, if I put http://www.thepayrollcloud.com/wp-content/themes/apex/apex-email.php as the URL for the ajax call, it doesn't work. It *is* calling the file from their local site.... but when I replace that so their site is calling the apex-email.php file from *our* site, it works, and that's cross-origin.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to play around with your code, I think its better to replace the contents of the div like:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mycompanysstagingsite.com/wp-content/themes/apex/apex-email.php', 
            data: $("#apex-form").serialize(),
            success: function(d){
                   $(".form-wrap").hide();
                   $(".result").html(d);
            }
        });
    }
```

also i added wrap around the form and add empty div with class results:

```
<div class="form-wrap">
    <form id="apex-form" class="form-horizontal">

         //your form contents

    </form>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Those divs are in the code already, but I didn't include it in the snippet on here because I didn't deem it necessary to solving the issue. Good call, though. :)